# How to get an object of all models of a Mongoose instance

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I know that [`mongoose.model("myModel")`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#index_Mongoose-model) returns the `myModel` model. But how can I get Mongoose to give me an array/object/list of all models, that are currently registered?

I think that somewhat is a design flaw.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As of now, there is an offcial way: [`Mongoose#modelNames()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/mongoose.html#Mongoose.prototype.modelNames()).

Comment: [The feature has been added](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#index_Mongoose-modelNames)

Answer (score 8):

You can get an array of all existed models using this:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var models = mongoose.modelNames()
```